# Subset data with the date format "01.01.2009 08:00:00, 01.01.2009 9:00:00, ..."

Tags: r, date, subset

I'm currently trying to subset data from my dataset. I used `dput` and `str` so you can see what I'm working with:

`dput`:

```
structure(list(Date = structure(1:10, .Label = c("01.01.2009 00:00:00", 
"01.01.2009 01:00:00", "01.01.2009 02:00:00", "01.01.2009 03:00:00", 
"01.01.2009 04:00:00", "01.01.2009 05:00:00", "01.01.2009 06:00:00", 
"01.01.2009 07:00:00", "01.01.2009 08:00:00", "01.01.2009 09:00:00"
), class = "factor"), SWC = c(NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 
NaN, NaN, NaN)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

`str`:

```
'data.frame':   8756 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Date: Factor w/ 96408 levels "01.01.2009 00:00:00",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ SWC : num  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ...
```

As you can see my dates have the format "DD MM YY HH MM SS". In order to subset my data I tried using the `subset()` function (see below).

```
Mois2009_2 <- subset(Mois1$Date <= "31.12.2009 23:00:00")
```

**But I got following error:**

> ```
> In Ops.factor(Mois1$Date, "31.12.2009 23:00:00") :
>       ‘<=’ not meaningful for factors
> ```

I looked up the error and found that I have to convert my dates by using

```
as.Date(Mois1$Date)
```

which produced another **error** which says:

> `Character string is not in a unique standard format`.

I just started working with R so I'd appreciate some help!

Comment: Phil once you convert the data to a date, assuming it was interpreted correctly, then you also need to have your filtering condition in standard iso date format. That is "2009-12-31 23:00:00" .  A more simple way to subset your data would be to use a grepl function. grepl finds strings within strings, such as "2009". So  `my_list_object[grepl("2009", my_list_object)]` would get you what you are after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could solve it as follows:

```
Mois1 <- structure(list(Date = structure(1:10, .Label = c("01.01.2009 00:00:00", 
                   "01.01.2009 01:00:00", "01.01.2009 02:00:00", "01.01.2009 03:00:00", 
                   "01.01.2009 04:00:00", "01.01.2009 05:00:00", "01.01.2009 06:00:00", 
                   "01.01.2009 07:00:00", "01.01.2009 08:00:00", "01.01.2009 09:00:00"
                   ), class = "factor"), SWC = c(NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 
                   NaN, NaN, NaN)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")

Mois1$Date <- as.Date(Mois1$Date, format = "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")
Mois2009_2 <- subset(Mois1, Date <= "2009-12-31 23:00:00")
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `filter` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df1 %>%
    filter(dmy_hms(Date) <= "2009-12-31 23:00:00")
```

Comment: @SKyJim I tried using grepl():  `M2009 <- Mois1[grepl("2009", Mois1)]`

But that just returns the whole dataset and does not only include values with "2009" in it. 
I looked up the mode of the column with the Date in it and it says "numeric" so I also think that looking for characters doesn't help here.

Comment: If I type `Mois1%>% 
  filter(dmy_hms(Date) <= "2009-12-31 23:00:00")` it says: _couldn't find the function %>%_

Comment: @B. Christian Kamgang
Thank you so much, that worked! 
However I do have the problem now that the time is missing in the column now. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: @Phil perhaps you want to comment on the other post?